# How does OCaml infer the type in this case?

Tags: ocaml

```
type 'a lazy_node = 
  | Empty
  | Node of 'a * 'a lazy_list
and 'a lazy_list = 'a lazy_node lazy_t

let con x zl = lazy (Node (x,zl))
```

So there should be two types defined here: `'a lazy_node` and `'a lazy_list`.

I thought that `con`'s type would be `'a -> 'a lazy_list -> 'a lazy_list`

However, actually when I tried it in `utop`, it gave `con` such a type:

`val con : 'a -> 'a lazy_list -> 'a lazy_node lazy_t = <fun>`

---

Why the return type is not `'a lazy_list`? How does OCaml infer in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code `lazy_list` is not a new type but just an alias for `lazy_node lazy_t`. And the Ocaml type inferer only consider real types, not aliases. So it infers the real type and doesn't check if there is an alias for this type.

The alias is used for the argument because `Node (x,zl)` implies that `zl` has type `'a lazy_list`.

You can add type annotation to enforce the use of the alias:

```
let con x zl: 'a lazy_list = lazy (Node (x,zl))
```

Comment: So you mean even `type 'a mytype = 'a list * int` or `type mytype = int * float` are not real types, just aliases? Could you please add more to your answer that what is real type and what is aliases?

Comment: When you write `type newtype = othertype` it creates an alias.

Comment: ok, got it, thanks. so `type 'a mytype = 'a list * int` is a alias as `'a list * int` is a tuple which already is a type, right?

Comment: That's it. Type equation are useful for functors (every argument module has a `type t = ...` type equation) but they just create useless aliases otherwise.

Comment: actually, type "aliases" are useful whenever you want to avoid writing the full type it aliases, which is indeed interesting for functors, but also for any other places where you might want to specify a type (a record, an object, a function signature, etc.). It's like defining a new word basically in your vocabulary and using it instead of its longer definition (which could be tiresome).